# update does not work in onStart Getx Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I have a getx Controller and I want to call a certain function and restart UI every time my Controller gets build... I use onStart function to do  this

```
 @override
  get onStart {
    getBalance().then((value) {
      update([1]);
    });
    return super.onStart;
  }
```

the code is fine if I use it in any other place it is ok but in onStart function, it wont rebuild my widgets
Can I use update in OnStart Function at all? is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: Why the `get` keyword before `onStart`?

Comment: @S.M.JAHANGIR it is built on its own... i type OnStart and it is created.

Comment: I don't think it is `get onStart{…}`. Can you change to `onStart(){…}` and see?

Comment: @S.M.JAHANGIR OnStart only work first time the Controller get build but i want a function to get called every time i try to Find Controller

Answer (score 0):

using `GetxController`, you need to call your initialization code inside the `onInit()` method like this:

```
@override
onInit() {
   getBalance().then((value) {
    update([1]);
   });
super.onInit();
}
```